# how to change font color and size of disable telerik:RadComboBox control

Tags: telerik

[image: Please click here to see Image]

How to change text color and size of disabled RadComboBox like RadTextBox in above image

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<telerik:radcombobox 
    id="RadComboBox1" 
    backcolor="red" 
    forecolor="yellow" 
    width="180"
    runat="server">
</telerik:radcombobox>
```

or in c#...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    RadComboBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;    
    RadComboBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;    
    RadComboBox1.Font.Bold = true;
}
```